# Javascript - after pressing the Key stays in a pressed state (returns true)

Tags: javascript, jquery

You have to click first anywere so shift pressing gets registered.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

  <title>Display Coloring</title>

  <script src="jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    div {
      background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      line-height: 0;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      display: inline-block;
      float: left;
    }
    body {
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      width: 1920px;
      height: 1080px;
    }
    div:hover {
      background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
    input {
      float: left;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      padding: 0;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
      box-shadow: none !important;
      outline: none;
      border: none;
      word-spacing: 0;
      letter-spacing: 0;
    }
    #conDiv {
      width: 1920px;
      height: 1080px;
      background-color: transparent;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    #conInput {
      width: 1920px;
      height: 1080px;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: -1;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <script>
    var body = document.body;

    a = [];
    b = [];
    c = [];
    i = [];
    d = [];
    clicked = [];
    altDown = false;

    window.onload = function() {

      conInput = document.createElement('div');
      conInput.setAttribute('id', 'conInput');
      document.body.appendChild(conInput);

      conDiv = document.createElement('div');
      conDiv.setAttribute('id', 'conDiv');
      document.body.appendChild(conDiv);

      //for(u=0;u<1911;u+=10){
      for (u = 0; u < 1901; u += 20) {

        a.push(u);

        for (v = 0; v < 1061; v += 20) {
          //for(v=0; v<1071; v+=10){

          b.push(v);

          var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
          newDiv.id = b.length - 1;
          conDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
        }
      }

      //for(u=0;u<1911;u+=10){

      // for(v=0; v<1071; v+=10){
      for (u = 0; u < 1901; u += 20) {

        for (v = 0; v < 1061; v += 20) {

          c.push(v);

          var newInput = document.createElement("input");
          newInput.setAttribute('type', 'color');
          newInput.id = c.length - 1;

          conInput.appendChild(newInput);
        }
      }

      function marking() {

        $("body").on("keydown keyup", function(event) {

          if (event.type == "keydown") {
            console.log(event.type);
            $('div').hover(function() {
              if (event.keyCode == 16 && this.id !== "conDiv" && this.id !== "conInput") {
                clicked.push(this);
                this.style.backgroundColor = "#b3ffb3";
                console.log(event);
              }
            })
          } else {
            console.log(event);
            $('div').hover(function() {
              if (event.keyCode == 16) {
                //if()        
                if (this.id !== "conDiv" && this.id !== "conInput") {
                  this.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
                  //console.log(event.shiftKey);
                }
              }
            })
          }
        })
      }

      function changeColor() {

        divs = body.getElementsByTagName('div');
        inputs = body.getElementsByTagName('input');

        for (var l = 0; l < inputs.length; l++) {

          if (inputs[l].id !== "conInput") {

            i.push(inputs[l]);

          }

        }

        for (var k = 0; k < divs.length; k++) {

          if (divs[k].id !== "conDiv" && divs[k].id !== "conInput") {

            d.push(divs[k]);

          }

        }

        $(document).ready(function() {

          $("body").bind("keydown", function(event) {

            if (event.altKey) {

              for (var h in d) {

                //if(d[h].id == "10272" && altDown == false){
                if (d[h].id == "2544" && altDown == false) {

                  d[h].style.opacity = "0.4";

                  altDown = true;

                }

                //else if(d[h].id == "10272" && altDown == true) {
                else if (d[h].id == "2544" && altDown == true) {

                  d[h].style.opacity = "1";

                  altDown = false;

                }

              }
            }
          });
        });

        $('div').on('click', function() {

          if (this.id != "conDiv" && this.id != "conInput") {

            if (event.ctrlKey) {

              clicked.push(this);

              for (var h in d) {

                if (d[h].id == this.id) {

                  $(d[h]).css('background-color', 'rgba(255, 255, 102, 0.8)');

                }

              }

            } else if (clicked.length > 0) {

              for (var clk in clicked) {

                target = document.getElementById(this.id);

                $(target).click();

                $(target).on('change', function() {

                  newColor = this.value;

                  parsed = newColor.charAt(0) == "#" ? newColor.substring(1, 7) : newColor;

                  r = parseInt(parsed.substring(0, 2), 16).toString();
                  g = parseInt(parsed.substring(2, 4), 16).toString();
                  b = parseInt(parsed.substring(4, 6), 16).toString();

                  newColorRGB = "(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")";

                  for (clk in clicked) {

                    clicked[clk].style.backgroundColor = newColor;
                    clicked[clk].setAttribute("title", newColorRGB);

                  }

                  clicked = [];

                });

              }

            } else if (clicked.length == 0) {

              for (var z in i) {

                if (i[z].id == this.id) {

                  target = document.getElementById(this.id);

                  $(target).click();

                  $(target).on('change', function() {

                    newColor = this.value;

                    parsed = newColor.charAt(0) == "#" ? newColor.substring(1, 7) : newColor;

                    r = parseInt(parsed.substring(0, 2), 16).toString();
                    g = parseInt(parsed.substring(2, 4), 16).toString();
                    b = parseInt(parsed.substring(4, 6), 16).toString();

                    newColorRGB = "(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")";

                    for (var h in d) {

                      if (d[h].id == this.id) {

                        d[h].style.backgroundColor = newColor;
                        d[h].setAttribute("title", newColorRGB);

                      }

                    }

                  });

                }
              }
            }

          }

        });

      }

      changeColor();
      marking();
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

if I press *shiftKey* it works and the divs get their color, but if I release *shiftKey* the state stays ***true*** and it keeps colouring until a refresh.

Here is the code:

```
function marking(){
$("body").bind("keydown", function(event) {
    $('div').hover(function(){
        if(event.shiftKey){         
            if(this.id !== "conDiv" && this.id !== "conInput"){
            clicked.push(this);
            this.style.backgroundColor = "#b3ffb3";
            console.log(event.shiftKey);
            }
        }
        else{};
        }
    })
});
```

}

Can I somehow tell the programm to react on release of *shiftKey*?

***UPDATE***

```
$("body").on("keydown keyup", function(event) {

       if(event.type == "keydown"){
            $('div').hover(function(){
                if(event.keyCode == 16 && this.id !== "conDiv" && this.id !== "conInput"){  
                clicked.push(this);
                this.style.backgroundColor = "#b3ffb3";
                console.log(event);
                }                           
            })
       }
       else{
            console.log(event);
            $('div').hover(function(){
                if(event.keyCode == 16){                    
                    if(this.id !== "conDiv" && this.id !== "conInput"){
                    this.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
                    }
                }
            })
       }
})
```

Now it changes the color on *shiftKey* and changes the color on *keyup* to #000000. But it still stays on *keydown* and if I hover over a *div* it pushes the object into my array without colouring.

I want it to colour on pressing Shift and doing nothing on releasing Shift.

What am I missing?

Comment: I think there is a syntax error in this snippet

Comment: You should post the HTML and create a snippet where we can run your code. https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: @Juan Mendes the code is there

Comment: It turns green when I press shift, and turns black when I don't press shift

Comment: yes it does, but actually it shoud do nothing if shift is not pressed... If you eneblae console.log(event.type) in the keydown loop, you will see after you press and release shift, the state remains at "keydown" for some reason and pushes the objects into array clicked[].

Comment: The code you are using is really messy (sorry), there's no need to track they keyup and keydown, just listen to mouse move and test if `event.shiftKey` is pressed. My answer doesn't solve your problem completely, but it's a more sane way to think about it, IMO. I gotta go, but I suggest you remove code that is irrelevant, you have to narrow your question to a single problem and remove every things else from the code.

Comment: With my example, you don't have to first click anywhere also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seem to need is the `mousemove` event along with the [`shiftKey event property`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/shiftKey).

One problem now is that you are not unsetting the handler for hover that was set when you pressed shift.

The main difference is

```
  function marking() {
    $("body").on("mousemove", "div", function(event) {
        if (event.shiftKey) {
             this.style.backgroundColor "#b3ffb3";
        }
    })
  }
```

I've modified your code below

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

  <title>Display Coloring</title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    div {
      background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      line-height: 0;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      display: inline-block;
      float: left;
    }
    body {
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      width: 1920px;
      height: 1080px;
    }
    div:hover {
      background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
    input {
      float: left;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      padding: 0;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
      box-shadow: none !important;
      outline: none;
      border: none;
      word-spacing: 0;
      letter-spacing: 0;
    }
    #conDiv {
      width: 1920px;
      height: 1080px;
      background-color: transparent;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    #conInput {
      width: 1920px;
      height: 1080px;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: -1;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <script>
    var body = document.body;

    a = [];
    b = [];
    c = [];
    i = [];
    d = [];
    clicked = [];
    altDown = false;

    window.onload = function() {

      conInput = document.createElement('div');
      conInput.setAttribute('id', 'conInput');
      document.body.appendChild(conInput);

      conDiv = document.createElement('div');
      conDiv.setAttribute('id', 'conDiv');
      document.body.appendChild(conDiv);

      //for(u=0;u<1911;u+=10){
      for (u = 0; u < 1901; u += 20) {

        a.push(u);

        for (v = 0; v < 1061; v += 20) {
          //for(v=0; v<1071; v+=10){

          b.push(v);

          var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
          newDiv.id = b.length - 1;
          conDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
        }
      }

      //for(u=0;u<1911;u+=10){

      // for(v=0; v<1071; v+=10){
      for (u = 0; u < 1901; u += 20) {

        for (v = 0; v < 1061; v += 20) {

          c.push(v);

          var newInput = document.createElement("input");
          newInput.setAttribute('type', 'color');
          newInput.id = c.length - 1;

          conInput.appendChild(newInput);
        }
      }

      function marking() {

        $("body").on("mousemove", "div", function(event) {              
          if (event.shiftKey) {
             this.style.backgroundColor =  "#b3ffb3";
          }
        })
      }

      function changeColor() {

        divs = body.getElementsByTagName('div');
        inputs = body.getElementsByTagName('input');

        for (var l = 0; l < inputs.length; l++) {

          if (inputs[l].id !== "conInput") {

            i.push(inputs[l]);

          }

        }

        for (var k = 0; k < divs.length; k++) {

          if (divs[k].id !== "conDiv" && divs[k].id !== "conInput") {

            d.push(divs[k]);

          }

        }

        $(document).ready(function() {

          $("body").bind("keydown", function(event) {

            if (event.altKey) {

              for (var h in d) {

                //if(d[h].id == "10272" && altDown == false){
                if (d[h].id == "2544" && altDown == false) {

                  d[h].style.opacity = "0.4";

                  altDown = true;

                }

                //else if(d[h].id == "10272" && altDown == true) {
                else if (d[h].id == "2544" && altDown == true) {

                  d[h].style.opacity = "1";

                  altDown = false;

                }

              }
            }
          });
        });

        $('div').on('click', function() {

          if (this.id != "conDiv" && this.id != "conInput") {

            if (event.ctrlKey) {

              clicked.push(this);

              for (var h in d) {

                if (d[h].id == this.id) {

                  $(d[h]).css('background-color', 'rgba(255, 255, 102, 0.8)');

                }

              }

            } else if (clicked.length > 0) {

              for (var clk in clicked) {

                target = document.getElementById(this.id);

                $(target).click();

                $(target).on('change', function() {

                  newColor = this.value;

                  parsed = newColor.charAt(0) == "#" ? newColor.substring(1, 7) : newColor;

                  r = parseInt(parsed.substring(0, 2), 16).toString();
                  g = parseInt(parsed.substring(2, 4), 16).toString();
                  b = parseInt(parsed.substring(4, 6), 16).toString();

                  newColorRGB = "(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")";

                  for (clk in clicked) {

                    clicked[clk].style.backgroundColor = newColor;
                    clicked[clk].setAttribute("title", newColorRGB);

                  }

                  clicked = [];

                });

              }

            } else if (clicked.length == 0) {

              for (var z in i) {

                if (i[z].id == this.id) {

                  target = document.getElementById(this.id);

                  $(target).click();

                  $(target).on('change', function() {

                    newColor = this.value;

                    parsed = newColor.charAt(0) == "#" ? newColor.substring(1, 7) : newColor;

                    r = parseInt(parsed.substring(0, 2), 16).toString();
                    g = parseInt(parsed.substring(2, 4), 16).toString();
                    b = parseInt(parsed.substring(4, 6), 16).toString();

                    newColorRGB = "(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")";

                    for (var h in d) {

                      if (d[h].id == this.id) {

                        d[h].style.backgroundColor = newColor;
                        d[h].setAttribute("title", newColorRGB);

                      }

                    }

                  });

                }
              }
            }

          }

        });

      }

      changeColor();
      marking();
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ok, this works pretty nice. Thank you. Is there a possibility to unset handler for hover? or is it better not even to try to?

Comment: You'd need to set the mousein and mouseout event handlers separately, so you could call `off`, I don't see a need for it but if you really need that that's what you would need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the code to undo the coloring in a `keyup`.

You have written the `keydown` correctly, but there is nothing built into that event that says reverse this code when the user is no longer on the key.

`keyup` is explicitly for the downwards click of a key and `keydown` is explicitly for the releasing of a key.